# Palidromes List using a function definition

Tags: python, function

```
input_list = ['tacocat', 'bob', 'davey']

def palindromes(input_list):
    for word in input_list:
        if input_list[word]==reversed(input_list[word]):
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")

output=palindromes(input_list)
print(output)
```

the output should be `[True, True, False]`
but its given me error

Comment: it prints true and false in seperate lines, not in a list. do u want the output in seperate lines or in a list?

Comment: if `word == "".join(reversed(word))`

Comment: the output should be in a list

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the string and check

```
input_list = ['tacocat', 'bob', 'davey']
results = [x == x[::-1] for x in input_list]
print(results)
```

output

```
[True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix of your code, there were many issues:

1. you were printing, not actually outputting anything (I added an output list and a `return` statement)
2. you tried to slice `input_list` incorrectly (just use `word`)
3. `reversed` does return an iterator, so the matches would always be False (use `[::-1]` instead)

```
def palindromes(input_list):
    out = []
    for word in input_list:
        if word==word[::-1]:
            out.append("True")  # used strings here, maybe you wanted booleans?
        else:
            out.append("False")
    return out

output=palindromes(input_list)
```

That said, here is a shorter version:

```
[w==w[::-1] for w in input_list]
```

output:

```
[True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would write return statement instead of print, then it would work. Also try just calling the function without assigning any variable